# Rigify jaw controller deforming throat

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting, rigify

I've recently picked up Blender and gotten started with character rigging, i currently have an issue where once the rig is generated and weighted with automatic weights (using rigify), when i move the jaw controler the throat gets "pushed in". This seems to be an issue regarding weight paint, but i cant really find how to fix it.

The controller with the weight which is causing issues seems to be the bone tongue.002. The problem is that i cant find any controller which has weight on the neck, so i cant really "move" the weight from the tongue to the neck controller. The strange thing is i can move the neck controller and the neck moves just fine, but when i select it in weight paint it says it doesnt have any weight, its as if the weight is hidden from me and when i select some bones the whole model goes pink for some reason.

I hope that wasnt too messy of an explanation. Any help is appriciated, thanks[image: Ive added 3 pictures that hopefully make things a bit clearer. The first showing the deformation of the throat, the second that the neck can still be moved with the nbeck controller and the third thatt tongue.002 has weight on the throat.]

Comment: Can you share the file? These questions are hard to answer except that's probably an issue with the weights. (But you already know that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rigify the bones you use to control the rig are non deforming, while all deforming bones are hidden in the 29th layer (counting 00-31).

You can also select a vertex and read its weight assignements in the "N" properties panel, and select the relevant vertex group.

When you select a bone that hasn't an associated vertex group (like all non deforming control bones) the pink colour states that there's no vertex group to paint on.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'll try your suggestions

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks friend!